# Excel ThisWorkbook.Names fails when called from a formula in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a fairly complex VBA function that needs to add a name into the worksheet in order to work. I have narrowed it down to the failing code below. If I run this code within the VBA editor itself, it works correctly. If I call it from a cell in a worksheet, ie =demo(), then it stops on the Thisworkbook.Names statement with no error message. Any suggestions pls?

```
Function test() As String
Dim rng As Variant
   Const TEMPNAME As String = "TEMP"`
   ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=TEMPNAME, RefersTo:="test"
   ThisWorkbook.Names(TEMPNAME).Value = "test2"
   test = "ok"
End Function
```

Comment: There are fundamental limitations to what user defined functions that are called from the worksheet can do. Quoting microsoft: "User-defined functions cannot perform actions that change the Microsoft Excel environment when called by a formula in a worksheet cell". Adding names to a workbook is such an action. See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1) for more information about this. Your best bet is probably to add a button that calls the VBA in regular macro mode instead of "formula" mode.

Comment: Thanks.  The real problem I am trying to solve is based on this article - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/236433/evaluating-formulas-greater-than-255-characters.  I need to call the WorksheetFunction.Filter function with a string of >255 chars. I have a UDF that dynamically creates the code for the FILTER function, but i cannot execute it normally due to the 255 char limit in VBA calling excel functions via Works sheetFunction call. So I cannot use the method described in the link earlier I am stuck.  The UDF is designed to return a value to a cell so buttons wont work .

Comment: Describe exactly what you need. Give an example that can be tested. Nowhere in your question did you mention texts longer than 255 characters.

Comment: Now that I know I cannot work around the 255 char limit, i have found another way to do the analysis i need that does not involve modifying names on the sheet from a UDF. Thanks all for the input.

Answer (score 0):

If this is important to you, you can use a workaround by indirectly calling your function as a text argument to the `Evaluate` method. However, this is not a recommended way, so there is no guarantee that it will work in new versions of Excel.

```
    Function Mytest()
      Mytest = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate("test()")
    End Function
```